# Separate $_GET information that is stored in a variable?

Tags: php, http, post, get

Here is my code:

```
$unparsed = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

$unparsed is then set to:

> action=invoiceStatus&invoice_id=TyoAnXtoQosWuZMQnNWLfR&amount=0.1&posData=76561198255906099&btcPaid=0.000112&currency=USD&rate=889.52&status=confirmed&exceptionStatus=false

Is there any way to separate the values from eachother?  For example, could I have a variable named "userid" and set it to the value of posData?  Thank you for the help, everyone!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
$exploded = explode('&', $res);
$params = [];
foreach ($exploded as $pair){
    $keyVal = explode('=', $pair);
    $params[$keyVal[0]] = $keyVal[1];
}
```

then you can access `$params[invoice_id]`

or you can use the builtin php function `parse_str($string, $results)` as per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: no need to build your own, php has a function for this

Comment: @Dagon true, but it seems to me Jake wanted to know how to do it. but yeah: `parse_str($string, $results)`will do the trick in online